# List all music files on device cordova/phonegap

Tags: cordova, media

I'm new to Cordova and I'm trying to build an app where I need to get all of the music files on the device. How would I go about finding them? I can use DirectoryReader to enter a direct path to the music folder, but I would like to automatically find it. Is this possible? Are there any examples that you know of?

Answer (score 1):

well, you will have to read recursively all folders starting from root.
Read root folder. If object is folder- read its content. if object is file- check it if it's media file and add its path to list.